# remove a column from a dataframe spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe with a very large number of columns. I want to remove two columns from it to get a new dataframe.

Had there been fewer columns, I could have used the select method in the API like this:

```
pcomments = pcomments.select(pcomments.col("post_id"),pcomments.col("comment_id"),pcomments.col("comment_message"),pcomments.col("user_name"),pcomments.col("comment_createdtime"));
```

But since picking columns from a long list is a tedious task, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use **drop** method and **withColumnRenamed** methods.

Example:

```
    val initialDf= ....

    val dfAfterDrop=initialDf.drop("column1").drop("coumn2")

    val dfAfterColRename= dfAfterDrop.withColumnRenamed("oldColumnName","new ColumnName")
```

Comment: Why are you renaming columns?

Comment: If i want to first check if the column present in the DF and only if it exisits then drop it .. how can i achieve it ?

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
val initialDf = ...

val dfAfterDropCols = initialDf.drop("column1", "coumn2")
```

Comment: Yes, But I have provided different syntax.

Comment: agreed this is a better answer.